# Sort a row with 7 values

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL,
assume that I got 7 integers in 1 rows (7,2,6,4,5,1,8),
and I need to get the greatest 5 value or least 2 value from this rows.

May anyone give me some advice?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? SQL is good at sorting rows and not columns.

Comment: I don't get it, is this single column with a comma-delimited list? Or seven columns? And your result should be 2 or 5 columns? Or Rows?

Comment: Are you mixing up rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to give example to us, at least show your tables to be more understandable. Here is general answer for your question.

You can use [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) command in sql. If it is `string` value then you need to `cast` it in order to use.

Here is example;

```
ORDER BY CAST(columnName AS int)
```